# Is it possible to detect TARGET when compile the project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app with two target, the lite version/target has google admob ad inside.
Now I use the code below to process.

```
//App_Prefix.pch
#define _lite
```

in appDelegate

```
// AppDelegate.m
#ifdef _lite

@import GoogleMobileAds;
#endif
@implementation  AppDelegate
```

Is it possible to detect TARGET when compile the project.
The code below can detect target,

```
  //-------------detect target
  #define _lite [ [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo]environment]objectForKey:@"TARGET"] isEqualToString:@"lite"]
```

but it is not suitable to the part before

```
@implementation
```

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use can define `Preprocessor Macros` for each target.

1. Go to your project settings
2. Select the target
3. In `Build Settings` go to `Preprocessor Macros`
4. Add macro e.g `APP_TARGET_A` for all the configurations (debug/release)

   [image]
5. Do the same for all other targets

Now you can use it same as you are doing it with your macros defined in your `.pch` file.

```
#define APP_TARGET_A
@implementation 
#endif
```

**Option 2**

You can have different `.pch` files for each target. Do copies of `.pch` file e.g `Target_A_Prefix.pch` `Target_B_Prefix.pch` and add it to project (uncheck all targets).

In Build Settings go to `Prefix Header` and set the path to `.pch` for each configurations. Do the same for all the targets.

[image]